# How to read this particular .dat file in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have successfully downloaded from the CPS supplement data from here:

https://www.census.gov/data/datasets/time-series/demo/cps/cps-supp_cps-repwgt/cps-voting.2018.html

and after unzipping, I now have the file: `nov18pub.dat`

I have tried many different read.table and read.csv forms on this data but I am unable to view this data. Can anyone help me with turning this data into a workable df?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a fixed-width data file.

If you read in the first 10 lines and look at the length:

```
library(readr)

con = file("nov18pub.dat", "r")
line = readLines(con, n = 10)
num_char <- nchar(line)
close(con)

num_char
[1] 1018 1018 1018 1018 1018 1018 1018 1018 1018 1018
```

it appears to be 1018 characters.

You can use `read.fwf` from `readr` package to read in the file. In this example, the first 5 columns are read in (and the rest ignored using `NULL`).

```
read.fwf("nov18pub.dat",
         widths = c(15,2,4,2,3,rep(NULL, num_char - 26)),
         header = FALSE,
         col.names = c("Household_ID", "Month", "Year", "Line_Number", "Final_Outcome"),
         colClasses = c("character", rep("numeric", 4))
)

       Household_ID Month Year Line_Number Final_Outcome
1   000110118096587    11 2018           2           201
2   000110118096587    11 2018           2           201
3   710004140617571    11 2018           1           201
4   761077501690006    11 2018           1           201
5   761077501690006    11 2018           1           201
6   067091706007561    11 2018           1           201
7   067091706007561    11 2018           1           201
8   067091706007561    11 2018           1           201
9   067091706007561    11 2018           1           201
10  691715007600067    11 2018           2           201
...
```

This document provides details on the column widths and codes for each variable:

https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/cps/techdocs/cpsnov18.pdf

In there, it mentions the format as well:

> Structure: Rectangular.
>
> File Size: 143,050 logical records; 968 character logical record length.

However, with the supplement data, the record lengths appears to go to 1018.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

Import Dataset > From Text (readr) > Browse > *select file* > Delmiter > *select Whitespace* > Import

Just need to try various delimiters. Whitespace worked for me.

Happy data'ing.